# Не загружаются данные карты Google

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Делал всё в точности как по инструкции: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start. В коде ничего не изменено, только подставлен API ключ в нужном месте. После сборки через 'Generate Signed APK' и установки на телефон, получается только это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как с этим бороться? Привожу весь код.

Activity

```
package napc.gmaps;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

activity_maps

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="napc.gmaps.MapsActivity" />
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="napc.gmaps">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Ключ сами генерировали?

Comment: Какой именно? API ключ, да, через консоль разработчика. А sha1 был прописан уже в файле google_maps_key.xml, который генерируется автоматически при создании активити по шаблону для карт.

Comment: Тогда проверьте права на интернет. В манифесте

Comment: Вот, они указаны тут в коде. Или требуется подключить что-то ещё?

Comment: по коду все нормально. просто не видно где ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Карта не показывается, если:
- на устройстве, которое вы используете для запуска приложения, не установлены `google play services`.
- Не задан API ключ для работы с картами в `manifest.xml`

Смущают строки в манифесте:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Добавьте:

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
   android:value="AIzaSyComUhEqr9BL4JjqJE05Lck4j1uABIU08Y">
</meta-data>

<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version">
</meta-data>
```

Для справки:
[Работа с картами Android](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/306-urok-139-google-maps-sozdanie-i-nastrojka-proekta-karta-kamera-sobytija.html)

Comment: Да, сгенерировал релизный ключ и воспользовался Вашим фрагментом кода. Всё заработало.
И вопрос. Может есть смысл использовать вместо "com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY", вот это "com.google.android.geo.API_KEY". Как я понимаю, так будет всегда поддерживаться актуальная версия. Сейчас 3, насколько знаю.

Comment: @iNaps, возможно, попробуй. Я использовал карты `v2`